# Do unopened bottles of Gin and Campari turn bad in extreme heat?

Tags: storage-lifetime, alcohol

just got back from a trip with 2 new bottles of campari and gin, then forgot them for 24 hours in the trunk of my car, in a hot day (30C degrees) :(

Should I just throw them away? or are they still good?

Comment: They should both be fine. Gin is a distilled spirit so it's not a stranger to heat.  I just tested ;) a bottle of Gin that's been sitting in my office for over 4 years and seen lots of 30C days.  The Campari should be fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't *turn bad*, in fact it may make it last longer. You may have *madeira-ized it* (see below)

Madeira wine is known for it's extended "shelf life" after opening because of it's unique process of being heated to as high as 60 degrees C (140 F).

You may find that in the Campari some of the sugar may have crystalised. This may *slightly* affect the flavour, but it most certainly won't make it *turn bad*.

Answer (score 4):

If they were brand new and sealed, I don't think you have anything to worry about.  As far as I'm aware, there's nothing in either of them that could go bad in a way that would make you sick, though I can't vouch for the flavor. Were they in direct sunlight?  If so, that might cause it to taste off, otherwise, I'd try opening them and testing that for yourself.